# Long-running shell commands from Rake that can be interrupted gracefully?

Tags: ruby, rake

In several projects, I'd like to have a rake task like `rake server` which will start serving that application via whatever means it needs. Here's one example:

```
task :server do
  %x{bundle exec rackup -p 1234}
end
```

This works, but when I'm ready to stop it, pressing `Ctrl+c` does not shut down gracefully; it interrupts the Rake task itself, which says `rake aborted!` and gives a stack trace. In some cases I have to do `Ctrl+c` twice.

I could probably write something with `Signal.trap` that would interrupt this more gracefully. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your case but I have just hit a similar problem with my rake task and the problem was that inside I was catching any kind of exception in a particular code block. It seems that was also swallowing the Ctrl+C. As soon as I started catching StandardError, Ctrl+C started working out of the box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
trap('SIGINT') { puts "Your message"; exit }
```

That should make the trick.

You can even add the `trap` at the task level.

```
task :server do
  trap('SIGINT') { puts "Your message"; exit }
  %x{bundle exec rackup -p 1234}
end
```

Comment: Nice and easy! Although, for ending gracefully, doesn't it seem better to use `exit` without the bang?

Comment: @NathanLong Depends on your definition of "gracefully". For the human eye it's the same :P

Comment: With `exit!` "No exit handlers are run." So any `at_exit do` block would be ignored. I think I'd rather let those run. Anyway, thanks very much!

Comment: @NathanLong yes, that's the difference, again, invisible for the human eye :P Let me update the response to match your requirements.

Comment: Could I stop a specify task from controller?